# Subclass is not abstract and does not override method in superclass when adding second method

Tags: java, inheritance

When adding a second method to the subclass, it gives the above error.

```
package roar;

public class Roar {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal a[] = new Animal[1];
        a[0] = new Cat();
        System.out.println(a[0].roar());
    }
}

class Cat implements Animal{ 
    public boolean roar(){
        return true;
    }
}

interface Animal{
    public boolean roar();
    //   public boolean gender();  <-- this method
}
```

Comment: When you add `gender()` to `Animal`, you must implement it in `Cat`

Comment: What is unclear in the message? If it compiled what would you expect cat.gender() to return and why?

Comment: First, You can not create an object for an Interface.

Comment: When you `implements` an interface with a non-abstract class, you have to implement all it's methods, whether you use them or not.

Answer (score 6):

The error tells you all. Implementing an interface means you hold your class up to the contract of the interface. An interface guarantees: Every non-abstract class that implements me, provides an implementation for all the abstract methods I declare. This might be because they contain it, or by inheriting it from a parent class.

```
interface Animal{
public boolean roar();
 //   public boolean gender();  <-- this method
}
```

If here you add this second method, you also need to provide an implementation:

```
class Cat implements Animal{ 
public boolean roar(){
    return true;
}
public boolean gender() {
    return true;
}
}
```

This will solve your problem. But having a `boolean` for '`roar`' or '`gender`' seems quite odd.

Comment: I get "does it roar" but I don't get `does it gender". I guess some animals have asexual reproduction...

Comment: @PeterLawrey see your point, then again one could argue that the roar of a lion is somewhat distinguishable from the roar of a chihuahua :)

Comment: Also, I would expect `roar()` to be a command, rather than a question. It could return whether the roar was successful.

Comment: indeed. I would guess for a boolean method canRoar() is more applicable

Comment: I can imagine some Exceptions for a command `roar()` such as `UnsupportOperationException` and `IllegalStateException` rather than `boolean` e.g. `File.delete()` returns a boolean, vs `Files.delete()` which throws a more meaningful exception.